# make a mailbox available for viewing as a website

Tags: email, web, exchange-server, imap, publish

The goal: make an exchange mailbox (or IMAP) available for (anonymous) viewing as a website.
Has anybody used any existing tools for this? I could use a web-based email client and try to strip out the sending abilities and hard code the account information, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to make it viewable to anonymous users, a web application using Exchange EWS services is the best method.  EWS has a full capabilities and is what apps like Outlook for Mac and Blackberry Enterprise server use to access mailboxes.  That way, you're using an API which you can limit calls to and restrict functionality at the web services layer.  You can also skin it so you're just looking at content you need and not entire folder views and other unneeded client UX.

For more information:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900168(v=exchg.150).aspx

It's absolutely the way to go for client application access to Exchange.